# How do I connect to an update site in Eclipse when I get an "Unable to read repository" ProvisionException error?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, certificate, pkix

When trying to connect to an update site in eclipse in order to install the Cucumber-Eclipse plugin, I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to read repository at http://cucumber.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/content.xml.
    Unable to read repository at http://cucumber.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/content.xml.
    sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested
   target
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in this case was at first misleading as all other answers with the SunCertPathBuilderException relate to missing certificates in the java cacerts file.

Here it was actually caused by a URL redirection.  The Cucumber-Eclipse website lists the update site for their plugin as:

> https://cucumber.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site

However, when navigating to that URL in a browser, it redirects to:

> http://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/

Note the added "**.github**".

### Resolution

If experiencing this issue for an Eclipse plugin, navigate to the update site URL in a browser and copy the URL from there after the page has loaded.  This should give you the true update site URL, which can then be added as an Available Site in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

http://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/

Use above link from "Install new Software" in eclipse

Comment: Hey and welcome on SO could you please explain your answer further. Maybe explain it in download steps. that way it is easier for the reader to find the answer. You should also not refer to a link as answer. The link can get offline. If that happens your answer becomes useless

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

http://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/

Use the above link from `Install new Software` in eclipse

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer to this for better presenting your question/answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/3519504

Comment: Yep, that is the correct update site.  The issue is that the update site provided by the developer was "cucumber.io/...." which was then redirected.  This redirection caused a failure when trying to utilize the update site in eclipse.  So while my question and answer refer specifically to the cucumber plugin, it was meant to be a more generic answer regarding the redirection of update site URLs.